# How to nest an image inside the link in react-draft-wysiwyg

Tags: reactjs, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

The `react-draft-wysiwyg` library is used

As a result, I need to be able to make images links.

So that the resulting html would be something like this:

```
<a href="some-addr">
    <img src='image-uri'/>
</a>
```

I've tried every possible way, but haven't found a way to do it